# Assigning salespersons to different cities program

Tags: python, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I was working on a problem of assigning 8 salespersons to 8 different cities, which are represented in below format.

[image: 8 Salesperson vs 8 cities representation]

The column represents Sales person and row represent cities.

1) The condition for assigning are :
1) Only one city per person
2) Once a city is assigned a salesperson , the rows and columns and diagonal cities cannot be assigned to another person

I am not able to recreate an example from memory , sorry for that , but the representation of cities and salesperson is correct.

I thought to avoid rows or columns for similar salesperson , I could use permutations from python which will give me distinct set of cities without overlapping and from there on I could check for diagonal values.

Here is my attempt.

```
import collections
import itertools

def display (l):
    list_count = 0
    k = ''
    for i in l:
        print i 
        list_count = list_count + 1
        if list_count != len(l):
            k = k + ','



cities =  [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
sales  = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

print_list = []

count = 0

for i in itertools.permutations([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],8): 
    print_list.append(i)
    if count == 2:
        display(print_list)
        #print print_list
        #print '\n'
        for j in range(8):
            print_list.pop()
        count = 0



    count = count + 1
```

I am stuck on how to check if a salesperson is in diagonal position to another Salesperson, If someone can extend my approach that would be great , would like any other explanation , would be helpful, I would like python as I am practising in it.

Comment: This is [8-queens problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle)

Comment: I think you're missing some detail. Why not just have salesperson 1 go to city 1, salesperson 2 to city 2, etc? EDIT: Ah, diagonal collisions.

Comment: @Cyphase Once a city is assigned a salesperson , the rows and columns and **diagonal** cities cannot be assigned to another person

Comment: @amit, yes, missed that :).

Comment: @amit could you show your approach to this question , do you see how can I extend the solution to remove diagonal cities

Comment: @avabhishiek google 8 queens.